# Appending jQuery element multiple times

Tags: jquery

For the html:

```
<body>
  <p>Para 1</p>
  <p>Para 2</p>
  <p>Para 3</p>
  <p>Para 4</p>
  <p>Para 5</p>
</body>
```

If we use the following code in a script

```
$(function() {
  let a = $('<span> span 1 </span>');
  $('p').append(a);

  let temp = $('span');
  for(i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    console.log(temp.eq(i) === a);
  }
});
```

```js
    $(function() {
      let a = $('<span> span 1 </span>');
      $('p').append(a);
    
      let temp = $('span');
      for(i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        console.log(temp.eq(i) === a);
      }
    });
```

```css
p { border: 1px solid green; }
span { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
      <p>Para 1</p>
      <p>Para 2</p>
      <p>Para 3</p>
      <p>Para 4</p>
      <p>Para 5</p>
    </body>
```

I expected the result to be true since the same element is append to all the `<p>` elements. Can someone explain why the result is false ?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it will always be false, because

```
var a = $("<span>span 1</span>")
```

creates an *in memory jquery object*, without a corresponding DOM node.

When you append this with `$('p').append(a)` you append multiple *new* copies with the original (in `var a`) still in memory.

So when you get the new instances with `temp = $('span')` you're getting them from the DOM.

Note also that `===` on objects checks if they're the same instance and also note that `$(selector)` queries are not *live queries* - they only get what's there at the time.  So they'll never be the same object as `a.length == 1` and `$("span").length == 5`

Secondly, you can't compare two jquery objects using `===` as they're not the same *instance* of an oject, here's a more succinct version of your test:

```js
console.log($("div") === $("div"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>div 1</div>
```

---

You could update your js to only look at DOM nodes

```
console.log(temp[i] === a[i]);
```

which would still be false as `a` is in memory

```js
$(function() {
  let a = $('<span> span 1 </span>');
  $('p').append(a);

  let temp = $('span');
  for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    console.log(temp[i] === a[i]);
  }
});
```

```css
p { border: 1px solid green; }

span { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Para 1</p>
  <p>Para 2</p>
  <p>Para 3</p>
  <p>Para 4</p>
  <p>Para 5</p>
</body>
```

Converting this the same as previously to look at DOM nodes only (excluding the in-memory issue) you can now see that comparing the nodes does return `true`.

```js
// derived example
console.log($("div")[0] === $("div")[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>div 1</div>
```

But comparing with an existing item would be false as you've taken 1 item and made it into 5. So `($("span")[0] === $("span")[1]) === false`

---

One file addendum.  If you compare the HTML (string) rather than the objects, then yes, they will all be the same

```js
$(function() {
  let a = $('<span> span 1 </span>');
  $('p').append(a);

  let temp = $('span');
  for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    console.log(temp.eq(i).html() === a.html());
  }
});
```

```css
p { border: 1px solid green; }
span { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Para 1</p>
  <p>Para 2</p>
  <p>Para 3</p>
  <p>Para 4</p>
  <p>Para 5</p>
</body>
```